# Search for places with an App Access Token suddenly stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

i am calling the graph API with an App Access token (grant_type=client_credentials) to search for places on facebook. Quering for

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=50.785361,6.0334127
```

Used return the search result reliably but suddenly stopped working with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

I have tested the call on the Graph API Explorer. With my facebook user's access token the request still returns the desired data. Other requests with this app access token still work, so the token is good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I can repro this with my app access token.  When did it stop working?  I know that in general, app access tokens *should* be used for writing to the graph, rather than reading from the graph.  So it could be a matter of FB changing towards this model.